# Spacing issue in Email Template

Tags: email-template

We have created a Custom(No Letterhead) email template with the name “B2AckReply” under “Unfiled Public Email Templates” and assigned it to Default Response Template in Web to Lead Settings. There is a small issue with the spacing of lines in the template. The template looks perfect when you receive the mail in Outlook, but when you receive the mail in others such as Gmail, there is less spacing between the text lines than required. Similarly, If I include spaces to make the template look legible in Gmail, the Outlook mails have extra spacing.

Please advise me on this.

Comment: What type of email is it, my guess is it'll be letterhead?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to tell you all the email type. It is Custom(Without Using Letter head).

Comment: Then i'd say it has something to do with the html in your custom email template. The formatting of HTML in EmailTemplates isn't the same as it is with websites, it isn't an exact science, and I'd say you would probably best contact a marketing/layout firm/person, who has experience in building email templates for all (read: most) email clients.

Comment: Try copying the content into notepad. There is usually hidden formatting which is removed when u add to notepad. Then add it back to SF.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a solution like [Litmus](http://litmus.com/) to get a snappy and repeatable handle on all the different email clients.

Then ask your nearest HTML email expert to sanity-check the styles (and/or resets) and markup you're using to generate the email. Some elements work really consistently (tables) and others don't (typography).

Getting complex HTML emails to display consistently across clients will be a world of hurt for someone who doesn't do it for a living :-( try not to rely upon pixel perfection if at all possible.